# How does ISP fix "no internet" situation?

Tags: internet, internet-connection, isp

When internet is down user reboots modem and if it doesn't help he calls ISP. ISP help desk tells user to reboot modem again, asks MAC address, does something and the internet is back again.

What steps does the ISP tech takes to fix the internet? What are the typical causes besides "storm broke the cable"?

Comment: That depends on the access technology. Could you elaborate what it is?

Comment: Too broad, ha-ha. Here is what an "experienced SE user" (that is a bm guy) should do. Downvote every question and close it as either "too broad" or "a homework". GJ experienced users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tech at the ISP can search for a disconnected modem by its mac address and, once it shows, clear its ip address at both ends (if necessary) to create a new connection.
I, for example, have a router her that I use for client's PCs and, about once every two months, it will start refusing to allow connections and I have to cycle its power to fix it.  Its the same principle on a larger scale.

Comment: Sir, don't waste time on this dead community of downvoters. Go to code ranch...